# Why do we include a $ in Linux folder names?

Tags: linux, unix

Under what circumstances do we prefix a $ symbol to a Linux/Unix directory name?

For instance:

```
cd $CVBLOB
```

Comment: `export CVBLOB=/tmp; cd $CVBLOB` -> you will end up in `/tmp`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `$` prefix means that the value is an environment variable.

For more information, see this [article](http://www.codecoffee.com/tipsforlinux/articles/030.html) explaining environment variables in Linux.

Comment: So does it mean that the directory CVBLOB directly gets added to $PATH?

Comment: No, it means `$CVBLOB` is a variable in and of itself. Open up a terminal and type `env`. It'll show you a list of all the environment variables found. The `$PATH` variable is just one, although it's probably the most common.

Comment: @user761350: No. And `CVBLOLB` is not a directory, it is a variable.

Comment: @user761350: No. Maybe your $CVBLOB variable expands to something with, again CVBLOB in the name, like /opt/CVBLOB. But it needn't. So the answer to your original question is 'never'. A variable is prefixed with $, and the name is more or less free to chooose. And it isn't related to the path. You may extend your path with a literal name or an variable, like `PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin or `PATH=$PATH:/opt/jdk-1.6.20_26/bin` but you have to do it. There is no automatic DIR->VAR-PATH.